# How to realize a callback in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

Maybe my knowledge about this topic is so small, that the word "callback" is not right here, sorry about that.

If I start an thread in any class/activity/other thread and after finishing I want it to execute some other code from the instance (class/activity/other thread) which started the thread, how do I realize that?

Currently, I do it like this:

Here is pseudocode.

```
// Method inside class/activity/other thread
private void startThread(){
    MyThread thread = new MyThread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

And inside the Thread

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private (class/activity/other thread) instanceAbove;

    public MyThread ( (class/activity/other thread) instanceAbove){
        this.instanceAbove = instanceAbove;
    }

    public void run(){
        //Do some stuff
        finish();
    }

    public void finish(){
        instanceAbove.MyThreadFinishMethod();
    }

}
```

I think this is not a good way, but can you give me an example?

Using interfaces is working for `AlertDialog`s, because I can use `onAppend()`. However, in this case, I don't know how I could use them.

Comment: See the thread computation as a promise. When the promise finished, you want to execute some other code. Why not use `CompletableFuture<T>` or better yet, `RxJava` or `Project Reactor`?

Comment: maybe my Q and A here is of use to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use an `interface` and handle the callback accordingly from your calling activity/class/other thread. Here is an example.

Define an interface like the following first.

```java
public interface ThreadFinishListener {
    void onFinish();
}
```

Let us assume you are instantiating a `Thread` from an `Activity`. Hence implement the listener in your `Activity` like the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ThreadFinishListener {
    // .... Other functions in your activity 

    @Override
    void onFinish() {
        // Do something when the Thread is finished and returned back to the activity
        // This is actually your callback function. 
    }
}
```

Now modify the constructor of your `Thread` class so that you can pass the listener to it.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private ThreadFinishListener listener; 

    public MyThread(ThreadFinishListener listener){
       this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run(){
        //Do some stuff
        finish();
    }

    public void finish() {
        // This will invoke the function call in your activity
        listener.onFinish();
    }
}
```

Now while initializing your `Thread`, you might want to pass the listener to it as follows.

```
MyThread thread = new MyThread(this);
thread.run();
```

I hope that suffices.

Comment: Is there any performance or style advantage of using an interface instead of passing an object instance like I did? It seems to me I pretty much did the same...

Comment: The problem with passing the instance is, it can go out of scope anytime. For example, you can start an activity, then start the thread and before the thread finishes, you go back to the previous activity. Hence the instance which is passed has gone out of scope and you will not find the desired behavior and might lead to a potential memory leak. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are welcome! :)

Comment: You should at least make the listener field a weak reference to not leak the activity. Regardless of using an interface or not.

Answer (score 0):

use `AsyncTask`:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      //before start code in background 
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    //Do some stuff in background
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
      //after code finished in background 
    }
}
```

And then call, `new MyAsyncTask().execute();`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong:
Yes I can execute code after my thread finished and yes it is running on the same thread as the instance above.

But there is nor reference to the objects of the Instance above, so I cant use them.

Comment: you can use this class as a inner class to reference to the object

Comment: Well you are right, but since this is not what I wanted to do, I can't accept this answer.

Comment: AsyncTasks are outdated now that we have alternative ways of performing something in the background with callbacks. Also, AsyncTasks tend to leak memory