# How can I add a custom progress bar before logging in?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a custom dialog that has a progress bar in it. What I want to achieve is to display my custom progress bar and dismiss it when I'm already connected to the internet or if I have successfully logged in.

From my code below, the custom progress bar will not dismiss and keeps on showing. Please enlighten me on what to do with this. Thanks for any help that you can give

custom_progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_circle"
        android:progress="80"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please wait..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.forgot_passw:
                Intent owner_forgotpassw = new Intent(OwnerLoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(owner_forgotpassw);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_login:
                if (validateEmailPassw()){
                    if(internetConnectionAvailable(5) == true){
                        ownerLogin();
                    } else{
                        progressDialog();
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}

public void progressDialog(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View progressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_progressbar, null);
    builder.setView(progressView);
    builder.show();
}

 private boolean internetConnectionAvailable(int timeOut) {
        InetAddress inetAddress = null;
        try {
            Future<InetAddress> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Callable<InetAddress>() {
                @Override
                public InetAddress call() {
                    try {
                        return InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
            inetAddress = future.get(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            future.cancel(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        }
        return inetAddress!=null && !inetAddress.equals("");
    }

private boolean validateEmailPassw(){
        String username = owneruname.getText().toString().trim();
        String passw = ownerpassw.getText().toString().trim();
        boolean ok = true;

        if(username.isEmpty()){
            textInputOwnerUsername.setError("Fields can not be empty.");
            ok = false;
            if(passw.isEmpty()){
                textInputOwnerPassw.setError("Fields can not be empty.");
                ok = false;
            }else{
                textInputOwnerPassw.setError(null);
                ok = true;
            }
        }else {
            textInputOwnerUsername.setError(null);
            ok = true;
        }

        return ok;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thats not how asynchronous calls are made, if timeout occurs, your code may show a progressbar and stops executing unless button is pressed again,
You should implement a thread and use an interface for callbacks, dismiss the dialog on connection or login completed event.Also you will not need to wait for x seconds if you are in background thread waiting for callbacks, (5 milliseconds is a very short time for a network call, even your ping might take upto 100ms)

And remember to keep reference to the dialog so you can latter dismiss it, i don't think your are doing that even in the code not shared in the question

[How to communicate with ui thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui)

[Easier example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620618/how-to-realize-a-callback-in-android)

In your class, outside oncreate

```
AlertDialog builder; //you can name it anything
```

In your progressDialog

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

instead of

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

And on connection or login event (or whenever you want to dismiss the dialog

```
if (builder!=null) {
   builder.dismiss();
   builder = null; //newbies safety
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. The progressbar will not dimiss unless I press something. How can I implement a thread and use an interface for callbacks?

Comment: @no_profile see updated answer, hope it helps, i have been coding in kotlin for a long time now (and you should do the same) so code may not be perfect but should give you the idea.

Comment: The thing about kotlin is it has coroutines, it can handle tasks like these in few lines of code with ease.

Answer (score 0):

1. assign an id to progress

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/progressbar_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:visibility="visible">

   <ProgressBar
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. create reference of layout in your code

   LinearLayout progressLayout = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_layout);
3. Once processing is done and you want to hide progress bar

   progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. my progressbar layout is from a different view.

Comment: Hinding something is not a solution to the problem, in this case, the progressbar is in an alertdialog which might still hang around if you somehow manage to hide its view instead of dismissing the dialog itself